# Is there a better way to integrate Landbot (ChatBot) into React Native App?

Tags: react-native, webview, chatbot, react-native-webview

Currently, I have embedded this ChatBot into a `WebView` something like this.

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import HeaderV2 from '../../components/HeaderV2';
import { WebView, WebViewNavigation } from 'react-native-webview';

export default function LandBotPage() {
  const botUrl = 'BOT_URL_HERE';
  const webViewRef = useRef<WebView>();

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <HeaderV2 />
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          ref={webViewRef}
          originWhitelist={['*']}
          startInLoadingState={false}
          cacheEnabled={false}
          pullToRefreshEnabled={true}
          style={styles.webView}
          source={{ uri: botUrl }}
          onNavigationStateChange={(navState: WebViewNavigation) => {
            console.log(navState.url);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {flex: 1 },
  webView: {flex: 1 },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are the ways you can implement this specific Chat Bot, I looked at the Landbot website but I couldn't find developer docs.

A general answer I can give you is that you can implement whatever look you want with `<View>` and `<Text>` and then call your Chatbot API endpoints with `fetch` calls. You can read more about fetching data in React Native apps in the official docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/network).

Comment: Yeah even I went through the entire docs section of LandBot, there is no official guide to integrating into mobile. It is currently web-only. But the above solution is a workaround for mobile.